# How to get difference between 2 group of records in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

Please consider this table:

```
ID       Code         Parent                        SomeInfo      Year
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1        11100        00000/10000/11000             SomeInfo1      2016 
2        11101        00000/10000/11000/11100       SomeInfo2      2016 
3        11000        00000/10000                   SomeInfo3      2016 
4        12000        00000/10000                   SomeInfo4      2016 
5        12100        00000/10000/12000             SomeInfo5      2016 
6        11100        00000/10000/11000             SomeInfo6      2016 
7        11101        00000/10000/11000/11300       SomeInfo7      2017 
8        11000        00000/10000                   SomeInfo8      2017 
9        14100        00000/10000/14000             SomeInfo9      2017 
10       15100        00000/10000/15000             SomeInfo10     2017 
11       16100        00000/10000/16000             SomeInfo11     2017
```

**Parent Column is a path to Top node(it is '00000')**

I have 2 Questions:

1) How I can Difference of **Parent** column based on **Year = 2016**. For example In above example **Code=11101** has different value for **Parent** column in Years: **2016 & 2017**.

Desire Output is :

```
Code              Parent2016                   Parent2017
----------------------------------------------------------------
11101       00000/10000/11000/11100      00000/10000/11000/11300
```

2) How I can get different codes that exists in **2017** and not exist in **2016**?

Desire Output is :

```
Code              Parent                   
-------------------------------
14100        00000/10000/14000    
15100        00000/10000/15000 
16100        00000/10000/16000
```

Thanks

Comment: Please include your expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first query, you can aggregate (`GROUP BY`) on the code column, and retain those codes having two distinct parents for the years 2016 and 2017.

```
SELECT Code
FROM yourTable
WHERE Year IN (2016, 2017)
GROUP BY Code
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Parent) = 2
```

There are a number of ways of answering your second question.  The approach I might use would be to self join the 2017 records from your table against the 2016 records from your table, and then check which former codes in 2017 do not match to anything in 2016.

```
SELECT
    t1.Code,
    t1.Parent
FROM yourTable t1
LEFT JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t1.Code = t2.Code AND
       t2.year = 2016
WHERE
    t1.year = 2017 AND
    t2.Code IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pivot the parents for 2016/17 using *conditional aggregation*

```
max(case when year = 2016 then Parent else '' end) AS Parent2016
```

And then apply

```
HAVING Parent2016 <> Parent2017
```

which results in

```
select code,
   max(case when year = 2016 then Parent else '' end) AS Parent2016, 
   max(case when year = 2017 then Parent else '' end) AS Parent2017 
from mytable
group by code
having 
   max(case when year = 2016 then Parent else '' end) <>
   max(case when year = 2017 then Parent else '' end)
```

Your 2nd question simply translates to a Correlated Subquery:

```
select code, parent
from mytable as t1
where year = 2017
  and not exists
    ( select * from mytable as t2
      where year = 2016
        and t1.code = t2.code
    )
```